# how to create cubes with druid using hdfs files

Tags: olap, druid, cubes

I am using druid for OLAP on Big Data.ai load data from hdfs files with contain many measures in dimensions, i want to know how Druid create cubes with this files and how to do query them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have tables of data stored in hdfs files , i want to load this tables in druid and than cretae olap cube with this tables ; so i can do queries ,

Comment: so how can i treat this tables as cubes in druid